# Facet wrap for many facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to draw individual plots for many (100+) cases, but facet_wrap squeezes them together to an extent where they are unreadable (see image). How do I adjust facet_wrap to view many plots (perhaps by scrolling down the output, since they won't fit on one screen)? There are enough cases such that full-screen doesn't help. Adjusting the "ncol" argument in facet_wrap doesn't seem to change much either.

```
m <- ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y = perf))
m + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ subject)
```

[facet_wrap output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHYLp.png)

Comment: What will you do with a plot to big to display on a single page?

Comment: If you just want a quick way to plot a whole bunch of cases to view visually, it's best to use some form of apply() + plot() + save-to-disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot will fit into the plot region in Rstudio. But you can save it to disk to make a large picture so that you can scroll. Try `ggsave`:

```
ggsave('Mydata.jpeg1', width =4, height = 400, units='cm)
```